# AS3 - Image smoothing

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

How to add smoothing to an image taken from a BitmapData array?

My code:

```
con.addChild(new Bitmap(myImage[0]))
```

Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
con.addChild(new Bitmap(myImage[0], "auto", true))
```

Comment: edited as you were applying the smoothing to the BitmapData instead of the Bitmap instance ;)

Comment: @Uli it's for `pixelSnapping` : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html